# HTML: "text-field" disappear in mobile view

Tags: html, css

I have this problem:
in HTML on the header I've got a text field and a button, when i visualize the site in mobile version the text field disappear and i can't understand why:
Here is my code

```
<div class="container-fluid header inner_head" >
    <div class="fixed_w">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <a href="index.php" class="logo">
                   <img src="img/logo_c.png" class="img-responsive mobile_none" align="center" alt="Mycity"/>
               </a>
               <?php//PHP code?>
               <form role="search" action="<?php ... ?>" method="POST" >
                    <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="search" name="searchProfile">
                </form>
            <a href="#" class="green_btn_header" id="ad">Add place</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap CSS
Thank you
Have a nice Day :)
Luca

Comment: And we should know why it's disappear? HTML code is fine, please create working fiddle with your problem.

Comment: ok sorry i'm new here in stack overflow , thanks ;)

Comment: I can't really reproduce the issue adding the bootstrap css to your example. Maybe also include more of the HTML?